# получить значения из БД и в списке select multiple отобразить их как выбранные

Tags: php, html, база-данных

проблема в том, что нужно получить значения из БД и в списке select multiple отобразить их как выбранные

```
<div id="form">

            <select name="apparat[]" id="type" size="10" multiple="multiple">
                <?
                $sel_aparat = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT used FROM products WHERE id = '$id_prod'");
                $sel_aparat_r =  mysqli_fetch_array($sel_aparat);
                $sel_aparat_array = array();
                do {array_push($sel_aparat_array, $sel_aparat_r["used"]);}
                while($sel_aparat_r = mysqli_fetch_array($sel_aparat));   


                $name_cat = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM aparat");
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($name_cat);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($name_cat)>0)


                {

                    do {echo '<option value="'.$row["name"].'"'.((in_array($row["name"], $sel_aparat_array)) ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$row["name"].'</option>';}
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($name_cat));
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        <div id="select_all"><input type="checkbox" name="select_all"><label>Выбрать все</label></div></div>
```

если в БД хранится только одно значение, то все работает, но тут может храниться несколько (на то и multiple)

var_export($sel_aparat_array);

когда выбрал один элемент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда выбрано несколько

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Структура массива неправильная, должно быть `array (0=>'value 1', 1=>'value 2', ...)`. чтобы ваш код работал

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: спасибо, за  консультацию. правда, очень помог, бился с этим неделю)

Comment: сделал вот так 
$sel_aparat_array = implode(" ", $sel_aparat_array);
 $sel_aparat_array1 = explode(",", $sel_aparat_array);
это привело массив в нужный вид

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблем возникнуть не должно, на всех необходимых строках должно установиться selected

Comment: я так тоже думал, при выборе и записи в бд одного элемента, в се работает, но вот если я выбрал несколько элементов, то селект вообще нигде не стоит

Comment: Значит ошибка в другом месте. Покажите var_export($sel_aparat_array);

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `do {array_push($sel_aparat_array, $sel_aparat_r["used"]);}` написать `do {$sel_aparat_array[] = $sel_aparat_r["used"];}`